# BufferedReader read() not working

Tags: java

I am trying to take input from an array and want to display, but for some reason, values are not getting displayed correctly.

Can anybody help me whats went wrong here?

```
package BufferBuilder;

import java.io.*;

public class MyArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter n");
        int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int[] input  = new int[n];
        System.out.println("Enter input element");
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            input[i] = br.read();
            System.out.println(input[i]);
        }
        //System.out.println(input[n]);
    }

}
```

In Output : I enter n - 4
And then array value 3 ,5, 7,  9
and output I am getting 51
32
53
32

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I updated my question.

Comment: May I know why downvoting this.

Comment: That's much better - now you get both an upvote, and two answers.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`br.read()` from `BufferedReader` (look below/[here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read()) for Java doc) reads a single character, so you get character *codes* instead of integers that they represent, along with codes of any punctuation in between.

You need to use `br.readLine()` and  convert it to an `int` value as shown below:

```
input[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

> public int read() throws IOException : **Reads a single character**.

**UPDATE:**

**I got java.lang.NumberFormatException error**
You need to ensure that you are entering only numeric values and NOT entering spaces or else you can use the below code to `trim` the spaces:

```
input[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

Comment: Geeting it but after that I got java.lang.NumberFormatException error

Comment: Am I missing anything

Comment: Did you replace the whole line from `input[i] = br.read();` to the above?

Comment: Can you update your current code in the question with heading updated code?

Comment: Updated., Please have a look

Comment: ensure that you are NOT entering spaces

Comment: Thanks for help. I was using spaces, I need to use enter is it ? Also If i want use this array for evaluation any where I can use that. right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139792/discussion-between-javaguy-and-shanky-singh).

Answer (score 1):

You should use readline instead of read in following part:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
     input[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readline());
     System.out.println(input[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but in this case i am getting `java.lang.NumberFormatException` error. Also one quick note In this case I am pritting my array in different line. Is it possible to print in same line.